# How can I achieve auto mounting AFP shared drives in OS X?

Tags: macos, network, afp

I would like to automatically mount remote AFP shared drives.

The ideal solution would be to auto mount the remote drives even before the session was opened.

**Edit**: I currently use login items, but as stated above auto mounting before the session or even without the session starting would be ideal.

Examples would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a shell script that I run via a launchd plist every few minutes to automount an NAS drive. I use it from home to mount my NAS as it contains our shared iTunes Media folder.

You can look at the script [Code on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DYUBe7dK).

I you have questions about the code I'll be happy to discuss. It has a lots of error checking etc. Using a shell script and a launchd plist has the benefit if the the mount becomes unmounted for any reason.

Comment: I will test that.

Comment: FYI, in _function mount\_disk_ the syntax for an AFP mount is `mount_afp afp://ip-address/volume-name $vol`

Answer (score 3):

You can put aliases to the remote volumes in your Login Items folder.

A nice explanation of this feature is available from Apple on the web and the built-in help:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2602

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell script that gets exectued with an AppleScript script.

Comment: Would you provide an example for a setup?